# Span.innerHTML returns text but Span.value returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a function that populates a pages with something like this

```
<span id="span_title_'+result_no+'">'+title+'</span>
```

and then I have another function that has this:

```
      document.getElementById("span_title_"+which_table).innerHTML="asg";
alert(document.getElementById("span_title_"+which_table).value);
```

The strange thing is the first (innerHTML) call works perfectly, the second one, the alert, gives me "`undefined`"

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`<span>` DOM elements don't have a `value` property. Use `innerHTML` to read the contents.

Comment: Ah! Thanks guys! I was told SPAN is exactly like DIV but without the linebreak so to use that instead... didnt know about the "no value" part.

Comment: Even `<div>` doesn't have a `value`. Only form elements have that property.

Comment: Hmmm, gotta check some of my old scripts again then! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

span doesn't have attribute with the name "value" only innnerHTML, you should use innerHTML for second call.